# How to remove my window in screenshot

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

I want to take screen shot in my application, for this purpose I create a form contains a button, when user click on button screen shot most create. But my screan shot contains that form which was showed! How to remove that form and take screan shot? I need that WPF form befor and after getting screan shot but during creation of shot it should close. How to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1- as @Richard mentioned you can use `WindowState` to minimize your form, take screenshot and maximize again. But you should wait till full minimization. So you should use `Thread.Sleep(...)` method:

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
Thread.Sleep(500);
/*Or every other value for waiting until minimizing was completed in mili-second*/
// take screenshot
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

2- also you can use `Hide` and `Show` methods for your form:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();

//When you want to take screenshot:
frm.Hide();
Thread.Sleep(500);
//Take screenshot
frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could minimise the window by setting [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before taking the screenshot then restore

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
// take screenshot
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: I used this code, but minimizing and maximizing actions are very fast and my screenshot contains the form. please test your answer.